# What is "drop if x==."

Tags: stata

Can anyone tell me, what's this line of Stata code doing?

```
drop if ratio==.
```

I know that `ratio` is a previously created variable, and `drop if` is saying delete rows in the dataset where `ratio` meets the condition. But I don't know what `==.` is in this context, and the docs aren't helping.

Comment: Simply put, `.` is a numeric missing value. The `drop` command thus is going to drop observations which have missing values for ratio. An alternative to `drop if ratio==.` would be `drop if mi(ratio)`

Comment: The `drop if missing(ratio)` suggested by @ander2ed is more robust in that it will work for both string and numeric variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used to check for missing (null) data.

> Logical expressions have numerical values, which can be immensely
>   useful. In Stata, the rule is that false logical expressions have
>   value 0 and true logical expressions have value 1. Thus logical
>   expressions may be used to generate indicator variables (also often
>   called binary, dichotomous, dummy, logical, or Boolean, depending on
>   tribal jargon), which have values 0 or 1. The command
>
> ```
> . generate himpg = mpg > 30
> ```
>
> will generate a new variable that is 1 whenever mpg is greater than 30, and 0 otherwise. Two wrinkles should
>   now be mentioned. What if mpg were missing? The rule is that Stata
>   treats numeric missing values as higher than any other numeric value,
>   so missing would certainly qualify as greater than 30, and any
>   observation with mpg missing would be assigned 1 for this new
>   variable. This rule leads to the next wrinkle: typing
>
> ```
> . generate himpg = mpg > 30 if mpg < .
> ```
>
> would assign 1 if mpg were greater than 30 but not missing; 0 if mpg were not >greater than 30; and missing if mpg were missing. The logic is that you did not >say what result you wanted if mpg were missing; in the absence of instructions, >Stata will shrug its shoulders in the only way it knows, assigning a result of >missing

From http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/